# An FTP client with image thumbnails?

Tags: windows, ftp

Can you point me an FTP client for Windows that can list directories with image thumbnails?

Also if it would do text editing directly on files would be nice.

Answer (score 8):

Unless you have very special server support, you can't generate the thumbnails or edit the files without first downloading them. FTP doesn't allow you to do this as part of the protocol. **WinSCP** is a decent client, though one of many which allows you to Right Click->Edit text files, though it's simply automating the process of downloading the file, launching your editor, and then re-uploading the file when you're done. If you're trying to work on a 100MB text file, you'll still have to wait for the entire file to download and upload.

If you need to work with large text files or need to edit them directly on the server for some reason, your best bet would be to see if you can get ssh access and edit them on the command line with `nano` or `vim`.

If you want thumbnails of all images in a directory, either download all of the images and let your OS create the thumbnails of the local copies (defeats the purpose if you're trying to pick which ones to download), or find a way to upload a php, perl, or other script to generate the thumbnails and make them available through a webserver. This will possibly require ssh to execute the script if you can't get access to a webserver.

Comment: SmartFTP has thumbnail file preview. It downloads all files in the background and display the thumbnails: https://www.smartftp.com/en-us/client/features/thumbnails

Comment: FTP Serv-U is a FTP server which has a special THMB command to obtain the image thumbnail: https://support.solarwinds.com/Success_Center/Serv-U_Managed_File_Transfer_Serv-U_FTP_Server/Knowledgebase_Articles/THMB_FTP_command

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SSHFS-Win (SSHFS for Windows)](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win) to add your (s)ftp server as a "Network location" in Windows. Then you can simply open it with Windows Explorer (or any other file browser) and enable the thumbnail view. This will also allow you to modify files directly on the server without the need of manually downloading and uploading them.

Comment: This is nice for exploring seamless! But at least in my case, Windows didn't show thumbnails in my FTP folder.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you might be better off with a document management system that is web based rather than a pure FTP server. You can look into something like SharePoint or Knowledge Tree. These provide the ability to upload and download like an FTP (not sure if they have a native FTP interface, but I know they can integrate with the file system via DAV), but they are web based so they can show thumbnails.

It would be a lot more helpful if you provided your usage scenario so we can cater the solution to your needs. For example, lets say you are a photographer and you don't want to download all of the 20 megapixel picture just based on file name. You can setup some type of FTP server that is also connected to a web front end gallery application. You browse the webpage to identify the images you want via thumbnail, then you go to your traditional FTP interface to download based on file name.

Unless you specifically need this to be an FTP interface for compatibility reasons, you might want to try a different approach.

Something that might work really well for you use case is https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload. I used this to let people uplaod files for me and it does image previews. There are obviously more sophisticated tools out there, but this is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

GNOME's default file manager (Nautilus) can do this if you enable thumbnail creation for remote files (that of course means it has to download all images first to create the thumbnails - maybe not what you want).